# JavaScriptでJSONの重複値を取得したい

Tags: javascript, json

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: hoge,
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: hoge,
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: huga,
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: piyo,
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: huga,
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: hoge,
}]
```

JavaScriptで上記のデータから `name`
の重複をみつけて以下のような値を取得したいのですが、やり方が思いつきません。

```
// 理想
{
    hoge: [1, 2, 6],
    huga: [3, 5]
}

// これでも問題なし
[1, 2, 6, 3, 5]
```

みなさんならどのようなプログラムを組みますか?
参考にさせてください。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

```
var temp = {};
var ans = {};
array.forEach(function(obj){
    var box = temp[obj.name] || (temp[obj.name] = []);
    if(box.push(obj.id) == 2){
        ans[obj.name] = box;
    }
});
```

これでどうでしょう

Answer (score 1):

学校の課題をそのまま出されてる感ありますが。。。

```
b = function(array) {
   var result = {};
   for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; ++i) {
       var l = result[array[i].name];
       if (l === undefined) {
           result[array[i].name] = [array[i].id]; 
       } else {
           l.push(array[i].id);
       }
    }
    // length=1なものを除去する
    var keys = [];
    for (var k in result) {
        keys.push(k);
    }
    for (var i = 0 ; i < keys.length ; ++i) {
        if (result[keys[i]].length <= 1) {
            delete result[keys[i]];
        } 
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: お、なるほど。length = 1なフィールドを消さないといけないのか。直しますね

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "hoge",
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "hoge",
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "huga",
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: "piyo",
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: "huga",
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: "hoge",
}];


(function(arr) {
  var m = {};
  arr.forEach(function(i) {
      m[i.name] ? m[i.name].push(i.id) : m[i.name] = [i.id];
  });
  for (var i in m) {
    if (m.hasOwnProperty(i) && m[i].length == 1) delete m[i];
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(m))
})(arr);
```

こんな感じでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

Underscore.jsを使うと、直感的に書ける気がします。

groupByで、nameを元にグループ化。
pickで、二個以上あるものを取り出す。
mapObjectで、結果を整形。
のようにやっています。

```js
var a = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'hoge',
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'hoge',
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'huga',
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'piyo',
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'huga',
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'hoge',
}];


var result = _.chain(a)
  .groupBy(function(o){ return o.name; })
  .pick(function(o){ return o.length > 1; })
  .mapObject(function(o){return _.pluck(o,'id');})
  .value();

document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<p class="result"></p>
```

Comment: mapを使っているところを、pluckで書き換えました。